# How to style container div as overflow:scroll when children divs are absolutely positioned

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I am creating a Bootstrap page that has two navs within a left sidebar - a top aligned nav and a bottom aligned nav.

Here is what they want that I am having problems figuring out- **They wish to have the the ability to scroll up and down the sidebar when the viewport is too horizontally narrow to see all contents.**

**Solution 1 -**

Per the code below I can absolutely position the bottom nav at the bottom of the sidebar.

**Issue with solution 1 -**

The problem I see with this solution is the absolute positioned lower nav is brought up over the top of the upper nav when scrolling since it is not in the document flow.

**Solution 2 -**

I have tried styling the sidebar as a table and the bottom nav as a table row.

**Issue with solution 2 -**

This brings the bottom nav to the bottom but the sidebar still does not scroll at all.

Any other ideas I can try?

HTML-

```
<div class="row">
    <aside class="col-sm-3 sidebar">
        <nav class="top-nav">
            <a href="#"><i class="icon-uniE603"></i>Foo</a>
            <a href="#" class="active"><i class="icon-uniE723"></i>Foo</a>
        </nav>
        <nav class="lower-nav">
                <h1>Recent Pages</h1>
                <a href="#">Foo</a>
                <a href="#">Foo</a>
        </nav>
    </aside>
    <main class="col-sm-9">
        <header class="page-header pull-right"><i class="icon-uniE603 header-icon provider-icon"></i>
            <h1>Home</h1></header>
        <h1>Welcome</h1>
        <p>
            Risea lettuce kohlrabi amaranth water spinach avocadf We'll help you manage and market your practice reens yarrow ricebean rutabaga endive cauliflower sea lettuce kohlrabi amaranth water spinach avocado.
        </p>
    </main>
</div>
```

CSS -

```
/* First Solution - Styling with absolute positioning */

    .sidebar {
        overflow: auto;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        display: block;
    }

    .lower-nav {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100% ;
    }


/* Second Solution - Styling with table positioning */

    .sidebar {
        overflow: auto;
        display: table;
        table-layout: fixed;

    }

    .lower-nav {
        display: table-row;
        vertical-align: bottom;
    }
```

Comment: I would try using jQuery if/else statements - if .lower-nav css === position: absolute; then the css of the sidebar is set to overflow: scroll; else the css of the sidebar is set to overflow: auto;

Comment: I updated the description of the post to clarify my issue. My problem isn't that it doesn't scroll with position:absolute. The problem is that the absolutely positioned lower nav goes over the top of the upper nav when scrolling. However, your idea might work for my display: table-row solution.

Comment: I meant that that particular element would have its own scrollbar so that it didn't sit over the upper nav when the width is minimal.

Comment: What are the browser requirements for this? You could use flexbox inside of the sidebar to position the elements properly. it would degrade to having the lower nav just sit underneath the top nav for older browsers.

Comment: This would be a great solution. Unfortunately I need to cater to IE9 and that is not supported. http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: Your code has no `.sidebar` element. Do you mean the `aside`? What are you using to display it next to the `main`?

Comment: Yes, I do have a class name of sidebar on the aside tag. I just left that off of there when posting the code to make it cleaner. I will add that in. The aside (or .sidebar) div is being displayed using the bootstrap col-sm-3 class.